# How to setup prompt with three nearest folders ../c/Users/test

Tags: bash, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

Here's a sample: `../c/Users/test`

I stil have no idea how to achieve this zsh's prompt, if possible also how it will be in `bash`?

EDIT: the `nearest` means my `pwd` will show for i.e: `/home/abc/c/Users/test`.
If I'm under `/home/abc/c` or `/home/abc` or `/home`, prompt should be `/home/abc/c>` or `/home/abc>` or `/home>`

So only current path that excesses three folders will have `..` appended in front and the three `nearest` folders.

Comment: What do you mean by "nearest"? In what circumstance would the prompt contain `../c/Users/test`? How is the relative (`..`) path of the path relevant?

Comment: @l0b0: I've just updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### ZSH

In `zsh` this can be achieved entirely with built-in features. You just have to place

```
%(4/|../%3d|%d)
```

in your `PROMPT` parameter (also known as `PS1`).

For example:

```
PROMPT='[%m@%n %(4/|../%3d|%d)]%# '
```

Would get you something like

```
[abc@machine ../c/Users/test]%
```

when the current directory is `/home/abc/c/Users/test`.

**Explanation:**

- `%(x|true-text|false-text)`: `x` represents a test, if it evaluates to *true* it `zsh` will print what is placed as *true-text* else it will print the *false-text*.
- `4/` is *true* if the current absolute path has at least 4 elements. For example `/home/abc/c/Users/test` has 5 elements
- So, if the current path has 4 or more elements, the output is `../%3d`, where `%3d` will be replaced with the last 3 elements of the current path. For example `../c/Users/test`.
- If the current path has less than 4 elements, the output is `%d`, which will be replaced by the full current path.

### BASH

#### Method 1: simple but not a perfect match

In `bash` (since version 4) you can achieve very similar results by setting `PROMPT_DIRTRIM=3` and placing `\w` in `PS1`. This will also only display the last 3 elements of the current path, preceded by either `~/.../` or `.../`. Which depends on whether the current directory is within the user's home directory.

For example:

```
PS1='[\u@\h \w]\$ '
PROMPT_DIRTRIM=3
```

would get you

```
[abc@machine ~/.../c/Users/test]$
```

when the current working directory is `/home/abc/c/Users/test` and

```
[abc@machine .../share/doc/sometool]$
```

when the current working directory is `/usr/local/share/doc/sometool`.

#### Method 2: complicated but works as asked

For an exact match place the following in your `PS1`:

```
$(a=${PWD%/*} a=${a%/*} a=${a%/*}; echo ${PWD/#$a/${a:+..}})
```

For example

```
PS1='[\u@\h $(a=${PWD%/*} a=${a%/*} a=${a%/*}; echo ${PWD/#$a/${a:+..}})]\$ '
```

**Important:** At least the part that generates the path output needs to be fully quoted, e.g. surrounded by single quotes. Otherwise it would be evaluated at the time of definition and not when the prompt is displayed.

**Explanation:**

- `$(command)`: This is called *Command Substitution*. It will run `command` and then be substituted by the resulting output.
- The parameter `PWD` contains the current working directory.
- `a=${PWD%/*}`: The shortest possible match to `/*` will be removed from the end of `$PWD` and the resulting value will be assigned to parameter `a`. That is, the last path element will be removed from `$PWD`.
- `a=${PWD%/*} a=${a%/*} a=${a%/*}`: this removes the last three path elements from `$PWD`. If `$PWD` has three or less elements, then `a` will be empty at the end. If there are more than three elements, then `a` contains all element you do not want to be shown, i.e. the ones you want to replace with `..`.

  (**Note**: While `a=${PWD%/*/*/*}` also removes the last three path elements, it does not work as intended, if there are less than three elements. In that case the end of `$PWD` would not match to `/*/*/*` and nothing would be removed, leaving `$a` to be identical to `$PWD`.)
- `${a:+..}`: if `a` is defined and not null this will be substituted by `..`, otherwise nothing is substituted. This means if there are path elements to be removed, then `${a:+..}` will evaluate to `..`.
- `${PWD/#$a/${a:+..}})`: if the beginning of `$PWD` matches `$a` then it will be replaced by the subtstitution of `${a:+..}`. Essentially, if `a` contains any path elements, than they will be replaced by `..`, otherwise nothing will be changed.
- `echo`: As this all happens within a *Command Substitution*, `echo` is needed in order to output the shortened path.

Comment: Many thanks, in bash I have `PS1='\w> '` and `PROMPT_DIRTRIM=3` but how to have only two dots `..`?
And How to achieve the same with cmd on windows 10?

Comment: I have added a method for `bash` that delivers the desired result without needing any external programs. I do not know enough about `cmd` to be able to help you with that, sorry.

Comment: With zsh, can we have mechanism to know that if `pwd` is current homeuser will have in front of path `~/home/USER` and any subfolders in home directory that exceeded three will have something like `/home/USER/c/usr/dir/cc` -> `~../usr/dir/cc`

Comment: How would to trim path `/abc/def/mnk/nothing` to `/d/m/nothing` that `d` is first character of `def` and `m` is first character of `mnk`. and always trim nearest three folders?

Answer (score 1):

this seems to do the trick:

```
PS1='$(pwd|sed -r "sx.+(/[^/]*/[^/]*/[^/]*)\$x..\1x" ):'
```

eg:

```
jasen@gonzo:/var/spool/news/comp/lang/c/moderated$ PS1='$(pwd|sed -r "sx.+(/[^/]*/[^/]*/[^/]*)\$x..\1x" ):'
../lang/c/moderated:cd
/home/jasen:
```

How it works:

`PS1` is expanded to produce the prompt.

I use  command substitusion `$(` ... `)` to insert output of a command into the prompt.

the command itself is a pipeline

first `pwd` pints out the current directory

it's output is piped (`|`) to `sed` in extended (`-r`) regular expression mode. sed is given the command.

```
"sx.+(/[^/]*/[^/]*/[^/]*)\$x..\1x"
```

this an `s` substitution command

in this command the symbol that follows the s is the separator here I used `x` 
  the phrase `[^/]*` indicates a seaquence of zero or more non-slashes (like the name of a directory) while the other slashes `/` represent actual slashes and `.+` matches anything at all (but not nothing). and the `$` represents end of line.

so starting from dollar it matches lines that end like `/name/name/name`

the bit after the second X where it says `..\1` is what to replace the match with.  in this case `..` followed by the bit contained in the bit matched by the parenthesised pattern.  `../name/name/name`

Comment: It would be more beneficial for readers if you elaborate the command's components.